# How to get java executable via Conda?

Tags: java, anaconda, miniconda

I need java 1.7, in a Conda environment. I installed OpenJDK Java 1.7 like this:

```
conda install -c anaconda java-1.7.0-openjdk-cos6-x86_64
```

So far so good. But, I do not have any `java` executable, and could not find it...

How can I execute JAR files then ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me the binary is in

```
<basedir of env>/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

Comment: But... why??? It is very complicated whereas executables are normally directly available for all other packages... How can I know what to put in PATH?

Comment: Why, I have no idea. It is about how the package is set up. Usually, if you have a conda package with binaries, it should copy it in the bin folder of the currently active env, which is automatically on PATH. In this case, you need to do it manually

Comment: Side note: Doing `conda install openjdk` gives me `java` in `<basedir of env>/bin` which is expected behaviour

Comment: I am not seeing java in the base bin of the environment on Mac M1, instead it is in `<basedir of env>/jvm/bin`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to take advantage of a direct integration of the java-executable in your environment, then use this:

`conda install -c conda-forge openjdk`.

This installs the Zulu OpenJDK, which is an open source build of the Java JDK.

Conda-Link: [Click me](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openjdk)